# How do I add an SKSpriteNode with custom SKShader to a scene?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, sprite-kit, shader

I've got my shader perfectly rendered in the .sks file. The problem is to add it to the SKSpriteNode or any other supported node to display it on the actual game scene. Here is my code in scene initializer:

```
    let shaderSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: nil, size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
    shaderSprite.shader = SKShader(fileNamed: "Player.fsh")
    shaderSprite.position = CGPointMake(200, 200)
    shaderSprite.zPosition = 1000
    addChild(shaderSprite)
```

The sprite is not displayed at all, though I don't have any nodes with higher zPosition.
What is the best practice to use custom shader in a sprite kit game?

Edit:

I've tried three different shaders. For instance, the one from WWDC 2014 "what's new in sk" session:

```
void main(void)
{
    float currTime = u_time;

    vec2 uv = v_tex_coord;
    vec2 circleCenter = vec2(0.5, 0.5);
    vec3 circleColor = vec3(0.8, 0.5, 0.7);
    vec3 posColor = vec3(uv, 0.5+0.5 * sin(currTime)) * circleColor;

    float illu = pow(1. - distance(uv, circleCenter), 4.) * 1.2;
    illu *= (2. + abs(0.4 + cos(currTime * -20. + 50. * distance(uv, circleCenter))/1.5));
    gl_FragColor = vec4(posColor * illu * 2., illu * 2.);
}
```

Comment: post your shader code

Comment: Done, but I think it's rather a SKSpiteNode or SKScene problem, than shader's

Comment: Any link to a working example of SKShader usage in iOS8 would be much appreciated

Comment: try it with a sprite that actually has a texture or a color, I bet the sprite won't even show up when you aren't using a custom shader

Comment: Thanks, LearnCocos2D. In fact it did show up and even shader became alive when I passed a random texture instead of nil

Answer (score 0):

Oops, it was too easy to bother stackoverflow's sages. 
The problem was solved by just passing a dummy texture to SKSpriteNode initializer.

```
let shaderSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playButton")
shaderSprite.shader = SKShader(fileNamed: "TestShader")
```

or

```
let dummyTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "anyImageName")
shaderSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: dummyTexture, color: nil, size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
shaderSprite.shader = SKShader(fileNamed: "TestShader")
```

Comment: This is an old answered question, but you can also specify a color instead of a dummy texture. SKColor clearColor works without actually displaying anything.